# Blender Boolean errors with texture Object

Tags: modifiers

I'm a blender newbie. When i use Boolean to disapear and apear object , Some frame render have texture of Object apear on cube.I don't know is this error of Blender?  anybody have this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does the glitch happen when you use the "Fast" Method in the modifier ?

Comment: What do you mean “disappear”?